# Angular interpolation doesn't work in a simple template

Tags: angular, interpolation

I have the error declared in the component:

```
error = "xyz";
```

then I have a call to authentication service:

```
this.authenticationService
            .login(this.f["username"].value, this.f["password"].value)
            .pipe(take(10))
            .subscribe(data => {
                if (data.authenticated) {
                    this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
                } else {
                    console.log("just before Wrong cred entered");
                    this.error = "Wrong credentials entered.";
                    console.log("error is:", this.error);
                }
                this.loading = false;
                return;
            });
```

and I can see the console output:

```
console.log("just before Wrong cred entered");                          
console.log("error is:", this.error);
```

fine, but in the template:

```
<div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger">{{ error }}</div>
```

I still see the original value ('xyz'). What is wrong with this code, I tried some things, but I really don't understand?

Comment: are you using change detection onPush there?

Comment: @SonuSindhu I don't specify any change detection.

Comment: looks fine then, do you have anything else to share which can help to figure it out.

Comment: actually, in the parent component, it is onPush! I just found this out. So I need a workaround, to use this swith the onPush strategy. I didn't know the interpolation doesn't work any more, if onPush is specified.

Comment: so you are getting that error from parent component? then you can use markforcheck after got error

Comment: this worked. I injected its class it as service.

Comment: great, I always recommend to use the immutable props for the onPush so we can always send new reference to reflect the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `.onPush` as a change detection mechanism to improve performance, you may need to re-trigger the change detector manually using [`ChangeDetectorRef` to mark component for check and force re-rendering](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef).